# Diff content changes across renames

Tags: git

My project history looks like this:

---

- Edit files a, b
- Commit, rev1
- Rename files a, b -> c, d
- Commit, rev2
- Edit files c, d
- Commit, rev3

---

I want to view a diff of what the edits I made to the two files across these commits, but `git diff rev0..rev3` isn't helpful because I just see the deletion of files a & b, and all of the edits to c & d as one big add mixed in with the creation of the files.

How can I see a diff including rev1 and rev3 where ((a,c), (b,d)) are treated as the same files, without the file rename clutter in the diff?

Comment: Did you do `git mv a c` when you renamed the file? That should let git knows that these 2 are actually the same file in the history?

Comment: Nope, Git doesn't store rename information.  Doesn't matter whether you use git mv, or a manual move followed by git rm and git add.  Try it; git status will show the same result for both.

Answer (score 2):

Use `git diff -M`.

It can also be fine-tuned - `git diff -M90%` to detect files which are 90% similar.  (Not sure what `git status` uses by default)

Comment: I've tried `git diff -M` (and `-M90%`), but it doesn't produce any apparent change in the diff. I still see "deleted file a" followed by a bunch of red text, "new file c" followed by a bunch of green text, and not the diff containing the changes of rev1 and rev3 as if the files hadn't been moved.

Comment: Hmm, you need an expert :).  I only used this once before.  All I can think of is to have a look at rev1..rev2.  That's the easy case (100% similarity), if it's not working then there's no chance for anything harder.

Answer (score 2):

```
git diff -C
```

will diff across renames, and also detect copies.

As mentioned in the answer above

```
git diff -M
```

detects just renames.

Answer (score 1):

`git diff` will accept arguments of the type `<rev>:<filename`. Use `git log --follow <file>` to find the revision you want, and the name of your file at that revision.
For example (on my code, it was converted to C++ in the past)

```
git diff 44308:./draw.c draw.cpp
```

for you it might be

```
git diff rev1:./a c
```

I found I needed to specify the path to the file, otherwise git itself gave me a hint.